# How to position iframe behind a png img?

Tags: iframe, z-index

How can I place a iframe under a png img? can i use z-index?!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

To do a quick tutorial on z-index I would go to: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp and try it yourself. You should be able to use z-index in the CSS to make the image show in front of the video. Just make sure the z-index of the video is lower than the image in your CSS.